# Java WS: how to build a ElementNSImpl from a model object?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have an aplication which is an WS dispatcher done with java JWS that works getting a ws petition, selecting which ws must be called, calling it, getting the response, parsing and returning it back to the client.

To do this, I have a XML composed of a part with info related to my service and another part with specific info of the service that must be called, so 2 diferent calls could be:

```
<petition>
    <generic><servicename>ws1</servicename></generic>
    <especific>.... whatever....</especific>
</petition>

<petition>
    <generic><servicename>ws2</servicename></generic>
    <especific>.... whatever needed for ws3....</especific>
</petition>
```

And their returns;

```
<return>
  <generic><servicename>ws1</servicename></generic>
  <specific><city>bilbao</city></specific>
</return>


<return>
  <generic><servicename>ws2</servicename></generic>
  <specific>
   <person>
      <name>Olof</name>
   </person>
  </specific>
</return>
```

To do this I've use the label @XmlAnyElement(lax=false) in the 'specific' field of my model (both in petition and response) so, in my service, I get all the calls as a 'petition' with something inside (the specific part) that will not be parsed by JWS; I will parse it in the specific part of each service called using a marshaller and letting him know which specific model has to be used:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {})
  @XmlRootElement(name = "petition")
  public class Petition{
      ....
      @XmlAnyElement(lax=false)
      private Object specific;
      ....
  }

 (Same for the response object.)
```

This work well when I get the object from the services that I call and return it directly as an ElementNSImpl object in the 'specific' field but usually I have to parse it (usually the specific object that I return is not the same type of the object that is returned to me) and I'm not able to do it.

In that case I have to create a new object (from the type which I want to return), fill it with the info I've obtained and return it to my client. Well, I do it, I build a 'response' setting in it the specific data  object for the service and try to return it but then the WS returns nothing (a 200 HTTP response of length: 0) to the client...

Also, If I set, manually,  the 'specific' part of the response to 'null' the object is well marshalled and my clients receive:

```
<response>
 <generic><servicename>ws2</servicename></generic>
</response>
```

So I think that it's waiting for an 'ElementNSImpl' but I don't know how to build it from an object that is JAXB annotated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not in my best day:

ElementNSImpl its, obviously, an implementation of Element, so the only thing to do is to marshal the object to an element and to return it in the 'lax=false'.

This method does it:

```
public Element marshallToElement(Object specific, Class clazz) throws JAXBException{
        DOMResult res = null;
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        res = new DOMResult();
        marshaller.marshal(specific, res);
        return ((Document)res.getNode()).getDocumentElement();
    }
```

This way I can call it in each diferent call to diferent service and, there, I'll know which Specific class has to be used.